# check function is called in child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to make a custom dropdown but with custom children component. Within the children custom component, there's an onChange event.

The problem now is whenever I trigger the onChange which is for the checkbox, the dropdown is closed.

https://codesandbox.io/s/lr677jv7l7

Partial code

```
render() {

    const { className, onOpen, children } = this.props
    const { openItems, selectedItem } = this.state

    return (
      <div className={classnames('customDropdown', className)}>
        <div tabIndex="1"
          onBlur={() => { this.setState({ openItems: false }) }}
          onFocus={() => { this.setState({ openItems: true }); onOpen && onOpen() }}>
          <button className="btn">
            {selectedItem}
          </button>

          <div className={classnames('items', { 'show': openItems === true, 'hide': openItems === false })}>
            {children && children}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a _specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/).

Comment: @Andreas I did gave an example, try open the link and click on the select, then click on the checkbox.

Comment: **in the question itself** ... a link, which can disappear like a puff of smoke, isn't **in the question itself** - think of future readers of your question if the link goes stale

Comment: Yes, but... :) [How do I ask a good question -> Help others reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask/): _"If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - **but also include the code in your question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time**."_

Comment: styles.css is empty

Comment: @IvanMinakov fixed .

Answer (score 0):

You need to get rid of following line:

`onBlur={() => { this.setState({ openItems: false }) }}`

It basically says that when your div wrapping the button loses focus (eg when you click the checkbox) it should set the `state.openItems` variable to `false` and therefore it closes the dropdown.

**Edit:**
Check out working example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/jnq2rqwr53.

Basically use `onClick` instead of blur and then you add click event to your document, so anytime user clicks anywhere on the document it calls your `hide` method and closes the modal. This way the selected checkbox gets checked, but if you want to dropdown to stay open after the selection you'll need to somehow tell the `hide` function not to execute if user clicked on the checkbox. I did it using ids and simple condition guard at the beginning of the `hide` method.

Code looks like this:

**Hello.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import classnames from 'classnames'

export default class CustomDropdown extends Component {


  constructor() {
    super()

    this.state = {
      openItems: false,
      selectedItem: 'Please select'
    }

    this.show = this.show.bind(this);
    this.hide = this.hide.bind(this);
  }

  show() {
    this.setState({openItems: true});
    document.addEventListener("click", this.hide);
  }

  hide(e) {
    if (e.target.id === "1" || e.target.id === "2") {
      return false;
    }

    this.setState({openItems: false});
    document.removeEventListener("click", this.hide);
  }

  render() {

    const { className, onOpen, children } = this.props
    const { openItems, selectedItem } = this.state

    return (
      <div className={classnames('customDropdown', className)}>
        <div tabIndex="1">
          <button className="btn" onClick={this.show}>
            {selectedItem}
          </button>

          <div className={classnames('items', { 'show': openItems === true, 'hide': openItems === false })}>
            {children && children}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**index.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './styles.css';

const styles = {
  fontFamily: 'sans-serif',
  textAlign: 'center'
}; 

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
  }

  changeCheckbox = () => {
    console.log('something')
  } 

  render(){
    return(
      <div style={ styles }>
        <Hello>
          <div>
            my checkbox 1
              <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.changeCheckbox} id="1" />
          </div>

          <div>
            my checkbox 2
              <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.changeCheckbox} id="2" />
          </div>
        </Hello>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: that's the default behavior when user click away from the dropdown content, if I get rid of that line that's not a dropdown anymore.

Comment: There's a reason why I use blur and focus over onClick, now when you click on ur checkbox text or the area of ur dropdown content, the hide will trigger. Imagine if u have a list of li, you don't want to hide it when user click on it.

Comment: @CeciliaChan and how is blur going to help you with that? If you click on any other element your button loses the focus, blur is triggered and the dropdown gets closed as well. That's why I used the condition in `hide` fuction so the dropdown won't close if you click on the checkbox. Of course you can come up with more bulletproof way of doing this, but the main idea stays same. Check out this codepen: https://codesandbox.io/s/pml3l6k9om. Now dropdown won't close after a click to any of its child elements. Let me know if this is better and I'll update my answer.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/lr677jv7l7 In this example, you don't see the children got closed besides the checkbox. There's reason why I used blur, for example u have mutliple dropdown, other dropdown will close if u trigger a dropdown, u don't have to purposely close another dropdown if u want.

Comment: I am sorry but I am starting to get lost a bit here. What exactly is wrong with my last example? codesandbox.io/s/lr677jv7l7 Isn't it exactly what you wanted in your question?

Comment: it is what I want, but I want it using blur. I used blur for a reason.